# Set the orientation of objects in 3d space

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I have program in which I am drawing some shapes such as rectangle/circle/triangle etc. in 3D space, equidistant from the centre.

Example of two points which are equidistant from the centre `(0,0,0)` are

```
x1: 93, 313, 123
x2: -263, -135, -186
```

and there may be more points as well.

At these two points, I am drawing the shapes by something like

`glRectangle(x1, width, height);`

The shapes (rectangles/triangles etc.) come out very well at the starting vertex `(x1 or x2)` equi-distant from the centre. However, the shapes have wrong orientation in space as to what I am looking for.

I want centre of the plane of in which the shape lies to to be prependicular to an imaginary line coming from the centre. This probably can be solved by rotation of the plane but I am not sure about the approach to adopt. For the current example, let's say I have the vertex of the shape but how do I figure out **the plane in which the the rectangle is** and `rotate that plane` to make it prependicular (to the line coming from the centre of the space `(0,0,0)`)

Comment: I don't know the glRectangle function, but couldn't you calculate the corner points of your triangle yourself and then draw a quad or 2 triangles?

Comment: @niktehpui: There's no glRectangle function actually. I have written a wrapper to draw rectangles in a similar fashion.

Comment: @niktehpui: The problem is not about drawing retangles, but orienting the position/angle so that the `plane of the rectangle` becomes prependicular to a line fromt the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the center needs to be perpendicular to the vector C (Line between coord-center and rect-center), it should work like this (pseudo-code):

```
A = C x UP_VECTOR (CROSS-PRODUCT to calculate helper vector pointing in "sideway" direction of "rectangle")
B = C x A (CROSS-PRODUCT to get the local "up/down" vector of the "rectangle")
A = normalize(A)
B = normalize(B)
P1 = width/2 * A + height/2 * B
P2 = -width/2 * A + height/2 * B
P3 = -width/2 * A + -height/2 * B
P4 = width/2 * A + -height/2 * B
```

Hopefully this is understandable and right (didn't try it and had some trouble finding the right vocabulary)

Some additional informations:
A and B are helper vectors and are the local up and left directions on the rectangle, after normalizing they can be used to calculate the 4 points of the rectangle accordingly.
Also be careful if no rectangle is displayed it's probably related to the drawing order so just reverse the order then if front and backfaces are wrong...

Comment: @nikhetpui: I get the idea to do the cross product to get a vector prependicular to two vectors, but I am not sure what `UP_VECTOR`, `up/down`, `sideway` mean here. ;-/

Comment: the UP_VECTOR is what ever your up direction is e.g. (0, 1, 0) or (0, 0, 1)

Comment: if you look along vector C (center to rect) then A is the vector going perpendicular left and B is the vector going perpendicular up

Comment: btw if you change the up-vector in this equation you would rotate the rectangles

Comment: @nikhetpui: The requirements changed a bit. Instead of drawing at the points that we are thinking about earlier, I would have to rotate the already drawn individual objects (it could be images, videos player rectangle shapes as well) somehow by using by using something like `glRotate` in PushMatrix. Any ideas on how I could get the plane of an object and make it prependicular to a vector?